# How to find events that occurred in a timeframe (mongo)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure:

```
{ _id:ID1
  value: { data:{userData:{name:aaa,surname:bbb}}
           events:[
                    {even1tName:{timestamp:UNIX_TIMESTAMP,value:NUMBER}},
                    {even2tName:{timestamp:UNIX_TIMESTAMP,value:NUMBER}},
                    {even3tName:{timestamp:UNIX_TIMESTAMP,value:NUMBER}},
                    {even4tName:{timestamp:UNIX_TIMESTAMP,value:NUMBER}},
                  ],
            activity:{countEvents:INTEGER,totalValue:NUMBER}
           }
}
```

This is the output of a MapReduce pipe, I need to find using aggregation, what users have a certain amount of events and a certain amount of value (summed up), within a timeframe. Consider these are online buyers and I need to find those that have made 3 purchases within the last month or those that have bought of a total amount greater than $300.

Comment: If all those "event(N)Name" fields really  do change like that then working with the aggregation framework is not really going to be possible. Are the keys at least "consistent" i.e Is something always called "sale" when it is a "sale", with no other variation in the name?

Comment: the keys are standard, like : 'confirmedSale','registeredNewsletter','viewedProduct'

Comment: So you would only be needing the "confirmedSale" events right?

Comment: for this case yes, I have a dynamic system, basically I would like to count any event while aggregating, at the moment I count certain events during the MapReduce processing, resulting in the fields in 'activity'

Comment: Wait a moment here. The mapReduce output you are working with comes from your own written mapReduce operation? So why are these "keys" named this way? Where does that data come from? Is it actually orginally stored in "data" and not the name of a key? The aggregation framework ( in fact most MongoDB operators ) does not like working with changing key names. If there is another source to come from then it would be better to not have the keys named like this.

Comment: the map reduces is just a detail, this is the final data structure on which I operate, keys are standard and fixed: {'confirmedSale':{timestamp:1232883882,'value':100} a user can have many confirmed sales, in the 'activity' key field I keep the number of confirmed sales and the total value of confirmed sales.

Comment: You are missing my point. Using "data" such as a "sale" as a keyName is "horrendous" for MongoDB performance. If there was some way to avoid this then that is the bettwer case to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit light on information, but the main thing is that as long as there is consistent "keyname" naming in the documents then this really is not an issue:

```js
  db.junk.aggregate([
    // Match where type within timeframe
    { "$match": {
      "value.events.confirmedSale.timestamp": {
        "$gte": startTime, "$lt": endTime
      }
    }},

    // Pre-filter the array for required data
    { "$project": {
      "value": {
        "data": "$value.data",
        "events": {
          "$setDifference": [
            {"$map": {
              "input": "$value.events",
              "as": "el",
              "in": {
                "$cond": [
                  { "$and": [
                    { "$gte": [ "$$el.confirmedSale.timestamp", startTime ] },
                    { "$lt": [ "$$el.confirmedSale.timestamp", endTime ] }
                  ]},
                  "$$el",
                  false
                ]
              }
            }},
            [false]
          ]
        }
      }
    }},

    // Unwind array elements for processing
    { "$unwind": "$value.events" },

    // Group data
    { "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "value": { "$sum": "$value.events.confirmedSale.value"},
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    // Filter results on totals
    { "$match": {
        "value": { "$gte": 300, "count": { "$gte": 3 } }
    }}
  ])
```

However, due to the document structure you cannot really get more extensive than that. Such naming requires "path names" to embedded objects to be absolute, and this particular case does not do well for indexing either.

With some control over the document creation, then it should look more  like this:

```js
{ _id: 1,
  value: { 
    data:{
      userData:{name:"aaa",surname:"bbb"}
    },
    events:[
      { "type": "adCLick",  "timestamp": 1234, "value": 1234 },
      { "type": "confirmedSale", "timestamp": 5678, "value": 5678 },
      { "type": "confirmedSale", "timestamp": 4567, "value": 4567 },
      { "type": "something",  "timestamp": 9876, "value": 9876}
    ]
  }
}
```

Now that the field Name you were using here is actually now just a consistent "data" property, the query can be more clearly readable, do more with combined events that you cannot do, and also work in the use of indexes for performance.

MongoDB is primarily a "database", if you do not keep consistent naming paths then you will have performance and feature loss as a consequence. The aggregation framework is the "high performance" option over mapReduce with JavaScript. Working with a set key pattern is fine for the aggregation  framework, but if you vary that pattern, then your only option is mapReduce.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how can I get to discuss more with you about data structure in mongo? if you don't mind.